# Is it possible to turn a raw_input into a either a float or an int depending on what the user enters?

Tags: python, floating-point, int

Let me explain:

Let's say for example, someone had this:

```
guess = raw_input("Enter your guess: ")
```

I know you can use `int()` & `float()`
But that is where my question lies. Can you use **both** simultaneously?

Say you asked for a number 1-10. you'd think to use `int(raw_input())`, but what if a user were to enter `8.5`? It would break the program, because `8.5` is not an `int()`.

Can someone help me with this please?

--**EDIT**--

How would one do the following:

```
guess = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
if guess == 1:
    print 'ok'
elif guess == 2:
    print 'no'
else:
    # re-loop to ask them for a number, since the inputted number is not valid...
```

I need to know how to do the bit under the **else**. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is written in python

Comment: Just use `float()`. In case the user enters `'3'` it will become `3.0`.

Comment: What version of python are you using? The versions of python I have just round it when using `int `unless it had so many decimal places.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax I believe 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `float()`. In case the user enters `'3'` it will become `3.0`.

If you really care about using `int` when possible you can use `try/except`:

```
guess = raw_input("Enter your guess: ")
try:
    guess = int(guess)
except ValueError:
    guess = float(guess)
```

This will still fail if the user enters a string though.

Answer (score 0):

in general, you can set your try/except to only work with integers:

```
try guess = int(guess)
except:
   print 'Please enter an integer.'
```

after that, you can either exit the program or loop back to the input request to give them another try.